# Different alignment of Top menu and submenu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

Hi I am trying to keep my top navigation menu centered while left aligning the submenus that come out.  What do i have to change in order to accomplish this?  THanks!

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/services.asp">Services &nbsp;<img src="images/tri2.gif"></a>
        <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Massages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Body Treatments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Facials & Waxing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hair & Nails</a></li>
                       </ul> 
            </li>
         <li><a href="#">Packages &nbsp;<img src="images/tri2.gif"></a>
         <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Linky</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Linky</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Linky</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Linky</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Linky</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Linky</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </li>
          <li><a href="#">Specials</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
              </ul>     
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#container {
width: 740px;
margin: -16px auto;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
font: 100% Helvetica, Arial sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
}
ul#nav {
line-height: 23px;
padding: 0;
}
ul#nav li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    background: #006666;
}
    ul#nav li a {
        width: 146px;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
                }
                ul#nav li:hover {background: #990000;}
        ul#nav ul {
            position: absolute;
            padding: 0;
            left: 0;
            top: 23px;
            visibility: hidden;
                        }
            ul#nav li:hover ul {visibility: visible;}
ul#nav a:hover {color: yellow;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chuckie365/5LuCA/

Comment: Please edit your question add relevant code and fix your link to fiddle example . it doesn't work

Comment: OK i fixed that...this is my first time using stack overflow.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need here is an additional CSS targeting that `a` elements:

```
ul#nav ul li a { 
  text-align:left;
}
```

Heres is the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/5LuCA/10/**

Comment: One thing i noticed while doing a multi browser compatibility check is that in FF 26 it looks like that padding that was placed on that last ul#nav ul li a is causing the width of the box to increase with a white space on the right side.  Is border box property recognized in ff?  Any ideas for an alternative..i'm almost there :)

Comment: Found a solution.  Gotta use the Moz kit for FF.